# Android: How to use IdlingResource to wait for background tasks (Espresso)

Tags: android, executorservice, android-espresso

I would like to ask for help about something I could not implement last week. I was implementing some Espresso tests when I found out a serious problem.

Sometimes my tests succeeded but not always. The issue was that my app has several async tasks which I have to wait before checking test conditions. Usually, Espresso only waits for main thread tasks.

I am using Executors to generate new threads, something like this:

```
executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(MAX_THREADS);
```

And to check if it is idle, I'm using this:

```
boolean isItIdle = executor.isTerminated() || executor.isShutdown();
```

Obviously, this solution doesn't work.
Any help will be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot updating this post with the solution I have implemented. :(

My solution was calling executor shutdown everytime I need to know when Executor goes to idling state. So, I changed my checking method in this way:

```
executor.shutdown();
boolean isItIdle = executor.isTerminated();
```

Calling executor.shutdown() makes possible executor.isTerminated() method useful. However, it should be noted that we have to consider shutdown state (executor.isShutdown()) when we need to generate new thread.

I hope this could help someone! ;)